# Stress character is cut/cropped from top

Tags: css, font-face

The test is simple. A font face is applied to all the elements. for some reason, the stress characters are cropped from the top. This happens only for the uppercase characters with font lower than 300px. The problem is not visible for lowercase character.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]
The test source files are @ https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33841998/font-test.rar

live example @ https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33841998/test/test.html

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Hi, can you set up a live example, maybe in a JSFiddle? Download links to RAR files are extremely unpopular around here.

Comment: hi Pekka, here is the live example. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33841998/test/test.html

Comment: Looks ok to me in Chrome on OS X. What browser are you on?

Comment: I have problem both windows 7, chrome and on firefox.

Comment: @Pekka웃 here is the link of the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p9zjd/

Comment: I can confirm that the problem exists on Windows 7. This sounds like an issue that involves font rendering algorithms and the properties of the font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with the font, a problem that manifests itself in some rendering environments. Testing with the .ttf font in Word 2007, I see the letter È (E with grave accent) as E with no hint of any diacritic mark above it; the same applies to other letters with diacritic marks. If I select the text, I can see the letters placed very high, with considerable space below baseline and practically no space above the height of capital letters. It is as if the baseline were set very high. Setting a large line height value does not help.

Contact the font vendor, or the third party that was used to produce the font files. While waiting for a fix, consider using some other font instead.

Comment: Hi, There was a problem with the font itself. I have to reproduce the fonts. Thank you for the time and have a good day. :)